# POST/PUT not working with partial in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, partial-views

﻿I am using a single form for new and edit actions in my controller.

---

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => edit_users_path(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'form', :object => f %>
   <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

---

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path do |f| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'form', :object => f %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

---

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form.text_field :firstname %>
<%= form.text_field :lastname %>
<%= form.email_field :email %>
```

For boths the actions, `submit` doesn't work. The form is rendered fine. I added data from `rails console` to check for edit. It doesn't work either.

If I create 2 separate form for each, `new` & `edit`, it works fine. So i assume my controller code is fine.

Thanks

Comment: What does "submit doesn't work" mean? You click it any nothing happens? It goes to the wrong URL?

Comment: Nothing happens. Data does not change/update.

Answer (score 2):

Render the partial with:

```
<%= render :partial => 'form', :form => f %>
```

instead. If it doesn't work, check the input names in the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your edit and new files are using an |f| variable for the form builder but in the form partial you're using form as the variable. Try changing the fields in your partial to "f.text_field"